# Check target file for duplicate entry before copy data from source file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, uniq, duplicate

I am trying to copy lines from *source.txt* to *target.txt*. I would like this `bash` script to check each line on *target.txt* if there is duplicate entry before copy.

> **source.txt** contains:
>
> ```
> a$$a$$a
> b**b**
> c%%cc%%
> d##d##d##
> e^^e^^e^^
> ```

> **target.txt** contains:
>
> ```
> a$$a$$a
> ee$$ee$$
> ff__ff__
> gg@@gg@@
> zzxxzzxx
> bb..bb..bb
> e^^e^^e^^
> hh;;hh;;hh
> ```

on this scenario, I assuming that there only 3 entries will be copied to *target.txt*  which are:

```
b**b**
c%%cc%%
d##d##d##
```

My test code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "started"
programpath=/home/mysite/www/copyfiles

var str input ; cat "$programpath/source.txt" > $input 
var str target ; cat "$programpath/target.txt" > $target 

cat $input >> $target

uniq -u "$target"

echo "finished"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using `bash`? The `grep` command can do the job clean.

```
grep -Fxvf target.txt source.txt #>> target.txt
```

This will return those lines which are exist only in *source.txt*, then you can append these lines to your  *target.txt* with just uncomment `#>> target.txt`.

You may also needs to unique the *source.txt* before, to prevent appending duplicated entries if in *source.txt* file which `awk` also does the same at next.

```
grep -Fxvf target.txt <(sort -u source.txt) #>> target.txt
```

- The `-F` option is telling `grep` that match pattern as a string instead of regex.
- With `-x` option we are telling whole line is my pattern.
- The `-v` is the reverse match that if you miss it, that will output the lines which are exist in the both files.
- And `-f` is telling `grep` read my patterns from a file which is `target.txt` here.

**Or you could use `awk` instead.**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]=1;next} !seen[$0]++' target.txt source.txt #>> target.txt
```

- Add whole *target.txt* file into the array called `seen` with the key of whole line `seen[$0]`, and do `next` to read next line.
- With `!seen[$0]++` we are looking a line from *source.txt* which is not exist in array, then print it. Also add *source.txt* file lines into the array to prevent printing duplicated lines if exist in source.txt_.